# How to detect navigate out in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

On Load you load a Url.

How do you detect and fire an event when the user navigates away from a page? (example click on web page button/link)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When new navigation begins, i.e. [`Navigating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx).

Actually the same `Navigating` occurs when you type a url, click a link, etc.

`Load` occurs on the [form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx), or [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.load.aspx), when it loads. WebBrowser control [has no such event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_events.aspx).